# vim autocomplete for arguments within tkinter (python3) doesn't work

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, tkinter, python-jedi

I'm using vim together with jedi-vim for development (python3).
Usually, the autocomplete does trigger when one edits the argument e.g. of a function like in the following figure:

[image: Figure 1]

You start to type the first characters of an argument and the suggestions pop up or you can trigger the autocompletion by using the corresponding binding (default crtl-space).

In contrast to the previous case, the autocompletion fails if you want edit tkinter funkctions (depicted in the following figure):

[image: Figure 2]

Is there an additional library for tkinter/python that is needed for this type of autocomplete or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try jedi's issue tracker?

Comment: I just did, but unfortunately, I haven't found anything regarding tkinter at the the issue tracker.

Comment: Their issue tracker is not read-only.

Comment: The question is if this problem is due to jedi or tkinter or sth else.

Comment: And the author of jedi is a very good person to ask to. Probably better than random people on a very generic site like this where your chances of getting a useful answer are pretty slim.

Comment: I just opened an issue, thanks for you advice.